# How to add type to prop using react typescript?

Tags: reactjs

I am using last version of typescript.
I want to add type to prop.

```
const const SideBar = (props) => <div id="SideBar" {...props} />;
```

How to add. this props type ?

Answer (score 1):

Add an interface before the function:

```
interface SideBarProps {
 element: HTMLElement;
}

const SideBar = (props: SideBarProps) => <div id="SideBar" {...props} />;
```

Comment: I know that. But type is html elements. How to it type?

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the type like below

```
const SideBar = (props: Type) => <div id="SideBar" {...props} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using two methods for this: `type` and `interface`. There are minor differences between these two.

### Using `type`

```
type SidebarProps = {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: boolean;
}

const Sidebar = (props: SidebarProps) => <div id="SideBar" {...props} />;
```

### Using `interface`

```
interface SidebarProps {
   prop1: string,
   prop2: boolean
}

const Sidebar = (props: SidebarProps) => <div id="SideBar" {...props} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type is HTMLDivElement

```
const Sidebar = (props: Htmldivelement) => <div id="SideBar" {...props} />;
```